# using global variable in node js

Tags: node.js, express, express-handlebars

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
 app.locals.userinfo = req.user;    
 next();
});
```

i am using global variables to store user info as i need to display them in my main template.
is it good practice to store user info in variables or is there a workaround?
are there any performance issue in using variables?

i tried creating helpers but that doesnt seems to work.

passing value while rendering is also not possible as user info has to be displaye on nav bar that is part of my main template.

Comment: Why don't you put the user object inside `res.locals`? The middleware you have right now looks fine but I would suggest to have the user object set to `res.locals`

Comment: i was just wondering is it correct way to handle user information...stroing it in a variable or using cookie as @sinbar suggested

Answer (score 1):

You need [cookie-session](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-session.html) middleware to handle the user information.That is the normal situation in the browser-server architecture.
You can get value from session like

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.end(req.session.views + ' views')
})
```

The session Object is a constant obj in the server, which has a default survival time and can be change also.
And the cookie-session is a common architecture, whatever nodeJs or java or other server-side language.You may can do an analogy, all behavior is similar.

Comment: i am using express-session for cookie managment
`// For Passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'my key',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions`
i am not very good with node js.can you please guide how to do with this setup

Comment: You requirement is show userinfo at browser right? So you just set the userinfo as a key in session, and set it into response when you need it. I update some code fragment in the answer.

Comment: let me try that out.will update the status and thanks for helping me out.